# Laravel 5.2 - Use a String as a Custom Primary Key for Eloquent Table becomes 0

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to use email as my table's primary key, so my eloquent code is-

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserVerification extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user_verification';
    protected $fillable =   [
                                'email',
                                'verification_token'
                            ];
    //$timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'verification_token';
}
```

And my DB is like this-

[image]

but if I do this-

```
UserVerification::where('verification_token', $token)->first();
```

I am getting this-

```
{
  "email": "sdfsdf@sdfsdf.sdf",
  "verification_token": 0,
  "created_at": "2016-01-03 22:27:44",
  "updated_at": "2016-01-03 22:27:44"
}
```

So, the **verification token**/**primary key** becomes 0.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 262, accepted):

This was [added to the upgrade documentation on Dec 29, 2015](https://github.com/laravel/docs/commit/b8c09f70d39f8c6891978a54c250a2fe9ad94947), so if you upgraded before then you probably missed it.

When fetching any attribute from the model it checks if that column should be cast as an integer, string, etc.

By default, for auto-incrementing tables, the ID is assumed to be an integer in this method:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2790

So the solution is:

```php
class UserVerification extends Model
{
    // if your key name is not 'id'
    // you can also set this to null if you don't have a primary key
    protected $primaryKey = 'your_key_name';

    public $incrementing = false;

    // In Laravel 6.0+ make sure to also set $keyType
    protected $keyType = 'string';
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why `$incrementing` field is public instead of protected?

Comment: @MubasharAbbas Well your model has to match Eloquent. Now, why does Eloquent make `$incrementing` public and `$primaryKey` protected? It's pretty arbitrary. I'm guessing `$incrementing` did not have getter or setter methods in earlier versions of Eloquent (it now does) and they just didn't want to make a breaking change after adding them in

Comment: If you have no primary key (or composite keys, which are not supported by Eloquent), and you're trying to iterate such table with `chunk`, you can face the following error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'example.' in 'order clause'`. IN this case you need to explicitly define `orderBy` statement, which Eloquent is trying to attach to your query with the primary key.

Comment: Sad that these are the types of things Laravel does that prevents me from loving with all my heart. Wouldn't detecting the column type (like it does with so many other columns) make more sense?

Comment: @Ms.AmeliaS.Greene, Laravel is much more than Eloquent ORM. An ORM isn't supposed to offer a higher level approach to every possible SQL situation. There will be times when we would need to resource to, say, Query Builder, which allows us to use raw SQL and SQL elements.

Answer (score 36):

On the model set `$incrementing` to false

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

This will stop it from thinking it is an auto increment field.

[Laravel Docs - Eloquent - Defining Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#defining-models)

Answer (score 13):

Theres two properties on the model you need to set. The first `$primaryKey` to tell the model what column to expect the primary key on. The second `$incrementing` so it knows the primary key isn't a linear auto incrementing value.

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'my_column';

    public $incrementing = false;
}
```

For more info see the `Primary Keys` section in the [documentation on Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#defining-models).

Comment: It needs to be `public $incrementing` to match the parent class.

Answer (score 3):

I was using Postman to test my Laravel API.

I received an error that stated

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column" because Laravel was trying to automatically create two columns "created_at" and "updated_at".

I had to enter `public $timestamps = false;` to my model. Then, I tested again with Postman and saw that an `"id" = 0` variable was being created in my database.

I finally had to add `public $incrementing false;` to fix my API.

Answer (score 2):

keep using the id

---

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserVerification extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user_verification';
    protected $fillable =   [
                            'id',
                            'email',
                            'verification_token'
                            ];
    //$timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'verification_token';
}
```

---

and get the email :

```
$usr = User::find($id);
$token = $usr->verification_token;
$email = UserVerification::find($token);
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP 8.2 Laravel 8

This property primaryKey needs to be public:

```
public $primaryKey = 'CdCep';
```

Comment: Please keep the discourse here civil, even if you're frustrated or excited.