# How to print primay key as a string?

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-5

I have a table, from an old database, where the primary key is a string. 
When I print it on the screen, it is printed like an integer.
Eg. if the key is 8-001abc, on the screen I have 8.

This is my code:
model

```
protected $table = 'mytable';
public $primaryKey = 'mykey';
public $incrementing = false;
protected $casts = [
    'mykey' => 'string'
];
```

controller

```
$item = MyModel::where('somefield', '=', 0)->get();
return view('mymodel.index', compact('item'));
```

view

```
@foreach($item as $rowitem)
   <p>{{ $rowitem->mykey }}</p>
@endforeach
```

any idea?
thank you!

Comment: should be able to just use {{ (string)$rowodl->ODL_NUMERO }} as a last ditch attempt?

Comment: @PeterFox This does not prevent Eloquent to cast PK to integer

Comment: @Arcesilas possibly right, this might be what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582535/laravel-5-2-use-a-string-as-a-custom-primary-key-for-eloquent-table-becomes-0

Comment: no, {{ (string)$rowitem->mykey }} does not work

Comment: thank you @PeterFox, but if you read my code you will see that I already defined $incrementing = false

Comment: @lorenzo my apologies then, there must be something else in your code that's doing the casting? Try adding an attribute accessor to your model and  debug what value get's passed to the method?

Comment: In my view I print out the $item value

{{ dd($item) }}

and "mykey" value is correct. It seems that the casting is made in the "echo" phase