# phpMyAdmin Sets Column as primarykey but Laravel model ignores

Tags: laravel

I set 'username' column as primary key in phpmyadmin, but didn't set it in User model, why is it the model never treat username as primary key in laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Model define your custom primary key as below:

```
protected $primaryKey = "username";
```

Comment: must i do this? i already set the username in phpmyadmin as primary key.

Comment: yes, In laravel field id set as primary key , if you want to define your own primary key ,you must define it  as above.

Comment: Yes. The Eloquent / Doctrine DBAL can read from the database, but it does not retrieve table information. You have to set Model fields manually when you want special metadata applying. For example, `protected $primaryKey` will treat a column as the primary key. `protected $dates` will mutate the DateTime/Timestamp fields you pass as an array. For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Comment: but if i change the data structure from phpmyadmin eg: from int to string, laravel will return error right?

Comment: This may be what you were looking for. Related: "using a string as a primary key". Handy if you're using things like UUID http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582535/laravel-5-2-use-a-string-as-a-custom-primary-key-for-eloquent-table-becomes-0

Comment: laravel detects column structure changes but couldn't detect which column is primary key?

Comment: If you change in column structure in database you need to refresh migration and  laravel couldn't detect which column is primary key.

Answer (score 2):

Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key column named `id`. You may define a `$primaryKey` property to override this convention.