# Laravel 5.3 Auth facade is changing to a default authenticated user

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

So I have a custom login flow in my laravel website. Ther users are located in an external data store that are accessible via an API. The flow is basically this. (minified)

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $resultFromAPI = //call external API with email and password from $request
    if($resultFromAPI) {
        $user = User::find($resultFromAPI->user->user_id);
        if($user) { //user exists
             Auth::login($user);
             //dump( Auth::user() );
             return redirect('/');
        } else {
             $user = User::create([...]); //from $resultFromApi->user
             Auth::login($user);
             //dump( Auth::user() );
             return redirect('/');
        }
    }
}
```

If I try to login using `user2@example.com`, the dump will show that user's object. However, the second I'm redirected to `/`, `Auth::user()` will be `user1@example.com`
My local db shows these two user records, but it's defaulting to the first user. I'm using the default logout function to logout and clear the sessions, and I've confirmed that `Auth::user()` is null when the logout function is called. I'm stuck.

EDIT: I tried `Auth::attempt(...)` instead of `Auth::login(...)`, it didn't change anything

EDIT2: I started from scratch using a clean installation of laravel 5.4, rewrote the login part to this

```
if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
  $request->session()->regenerate();
  $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

  return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
}
```

instead of this

```
Auth::login($user);
return redirect('/')
```

Still same issue

Comment: Did you not forgot some testing codes somewhere like `Auth::loginUsingId($user_id, true);` or something like that ??

Comment: I traced the flow from calling `/login` to redirecting to `/`, including the middleware. (I'm using the `auth` middleware in the routes) I even searched the entire directory for `Auth::`, and got nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: Assuming the user with email `user2@example.com` have the id = 2, try to use `Auth::loginUsingId(2, true);` without calling your external api in the `login` method and then `return redirect('/');` to see if it will generate the same broblem !!

Comment: Still same problem. Redirects me with `user1@example.com`. I tried to echo the email (`Auth::user()->email`) and commented out the redirect function, and I got `user2@example.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the issue. My primary key was a custom uuid retrieved from my external api. I reverted the primary ley to be the default one (`$table->increments('id');` and it worked.

I [looked it up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34582694/1968825), turns out I could've done `public $incrementing = false;` insided my User model and it would've stopped Laravel from thinking it's an incrementing field, and that might've solved it, but I haven't tested that.