# Foreign key is incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-migrations

When I changed my primary key from increments to string (user_id) i now got an error in my migrations. I dont seem to see where I went wrong. my migrations files were okay until I changed from (->increments and the other one ->integer) to (->string on both). The problem is when it migrates clanmembers table, it says foreign key is incorrectly formed

My code before. Seem to be okay, nothing wrong with the migration in cmd

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('user_id');
        $table->string('fname', 50);
        $table->string('lname', 50);
        $table->integer('age');
        $table->string('gender', 10);
        $table->string('address', 50);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('clanmembers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('user_id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('clan_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('clan_id')->references('clan_id')->on('clans')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('bandrole', 50);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

My code now after I changed ->increments and ->integer into both ->string

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('user_id');
        $table->string('fname', 50);
        $table->string('lname', 50);
        $table->integer('age');
        $table->string('gender', 10);
        $table->string('address', 50);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('clanmembers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('user_id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('clan_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('clan_id')->references('clan_id')->on('clans')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('clanrole', 50);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.2 - Use a String as a Custom Primary Key for Eloquent Table becomes 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582535/laravel-5-2-use-a-string-as-a-custom-primary-key-for-eloquent-table-becomes-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table One

```
 public function up()
    {
        //
       Schema::create('table_1', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('user_id',100);
        $table->string('fname', 50);
        $table->string('lname', 50);
        $table->integer('age');
        $table->string('gender', 10);
        $table->string('address', 50);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->primary(['user_id']);
    });
   }
```

Table Two

```
public function up()
    {
        //
       Schema::create('clanmembers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('user_id',100);
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('user_id')->on('table_1')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
   }
```

Comment: this worked. thank you so much! I appreciate it. sorry for delay

Comment: welcome. i am also sorry to provide correct answer lately.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set string length
$table->string('user_id', 100);
for intiger type if length is not set it automatically go for default value 11.
But for the string, you need to set it.

Comment: I tried putting length already (exactly what you suggested) yet still the same error. Still foreign key constraint incorrectly formed

Comment: class YourModel extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    public $incrementing = false;
}

Comment: please specific your column as primary key in migration $table->primary(array('user_id'));

Comment: now it does not put user id in table. it says user_id doesn't exist