# different primary key other than 'id'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following User and Order table.

**User**

[image]

**Order**

[image]

And I have defined one to many relationship in a User model as,

```
protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
public function orders() {
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class, 'user_id');
}
```

Now I am trying to get the orders based on a particular user whose user_id is '1'.

```
$orders = App\User::find(1)->orders;
```

I have two modifications here.

1. I have added `protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';` in User Model.
2. I had to add 'user_id' parameter as  `$this->hasMany(Order::class, 'user_id')`

Now the question is that I want to know if the above modifications are correct to reflect the proper relationship and get the proper data as mentioned in the following code.

```
$orders = App\User::find(1)->orders;
```

**P.S.** I have just started to explore the Laravel.

Comment: Take a look  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582535/laravel-5-2-use-a-string-as-a-custom-primary-key-for-eloquent-table-becomes-0) for more info.

Comment: when you run that do you get the correct result? if not then no.

Comment: Usually when you change the primaryKey to what ever you want , after that all the queries with primaryKey or relations will reference with new primaryKey that you have set .

Comment: @lagbox, yes I do get correct results.

Comment: @AlirezaAmrollahi, Thanks

Comment: @DushyantJoshi if you could vote up the comment , would be appreciated