# GraphQL ID type correction - how to use String?

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I have a model with unique id's like `d192a9be-c1f8-4099-8e88-7333ca07866d`
When queried using graphql the result is `id: "0"` so it looks like it's trying to convert to `Int`.

How do I use String unique ID?

Comment: The ID scalar is suitable for use with either string or integer values. If you're getting an unexpected value in your response, you would need to share your relevant resolver code.

Comment: I use Lighthouse for Laravel with graphql-playground

Comment: How is the id field defined in your schema? Assuming it’s `ID` or `String` (but do use `ID`) you are probably hitting this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34715309. Not related to Lighthouse specifically.