# Auth::user()->id did not get all the id string and get sliced

Tags: php, laravel

I have database with id using uniqid(), and when i get the id with `Auth::user()->id` always return an id but get sliced. Example i have id `64538065859d9` when i try to get the id with `Auth::user()->id` or `Auth::id` i will get `64538065859`. The part `d9` is always missing.

This is my migration code.

```php
   public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->char('id', 13)->primary();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('role');
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

I have tried change the

```
$table->char('id', 13)->primary();
```

to

```
$table->string('id')->primary();
```

but still does not work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582535/laravel-5-2-use-a-string-as-a-custom-primary-key-for-eloquent-table-becomes-0

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a a string as primary key, please add these lines in your model class,

```
public $incrementing = false;
protected $keyType = 'string';
```

ref : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).